# Проблемы с декларацией политики безопасности в Google play

Tags: google-play

Если коротко, то у меня есть приложение под ОС Android, разработанное в Android Studio и загруженное в Google Play Market, которое я хочу обновить, но для этого мне нужно правильно заполнить декларацию "безопасность данных". Вся проблема в том, что я не могу понять, что означает "SPLIT_BUNDLE 9: Декларация политики — Раздел безопасности данных" (см. фото ниже).
Может, кто сталкивался с таким? Подскажите, где можно посмотреть расшифровку этих SPLIT_BUNDLE, поскольку уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с таким. Заранее спасибо!
[image: Письмо от Google Console]

[image]

Comment: Вроде бы всё более-менее понятно - у вас какие-то девайсовые ID передаются. Например либами аналитики или рекламы. Гугл это видит и видит, что вы это не указали при заполнении, о чём и сообщает.